# SqlConnection State Change in a strange way

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I've my SqlConnection:

```
        this._sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sCxn);
        this._sqlConnection.StateChange += new StateChangeEventHandler(_sqlConnection_StateChange);
```

and that's the method to catch the connection state change event:

```
    void _sqlConnection_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this._previousState = e.OriginalState;
        this._connectionState = e.CurrentState;
        log.WriteLog("Connection change status: previous " + e.OriginalState.ToString() + ", current " + e.CurrentState.ToString(), log.INFO);
    }
```

When I cut the connection during normal app activity, I have right response from the method:

*Connection change status: previous Open, current Closed*

But when I reactivate the connection (starting the database service), I starting get this event sequences:

- 09.10.41: Connection change status: previous Closed, current Open
- 09.10.41: Connection change status: previous Open, current Closed
- 09.10.51: Connection change status: previous Closed, current Open
- 09.10.51: Connection change status: previous Open, current Closed
- 09.11.01: Connection change status: previous Closed, current Open
- 09.11.01: Connection change status: previous Open, current Closed
- 09.11.12: Connection change status: previous Closed, current Open
- 09.11.12: Connection change status: previous Open, current Closed

The app is able to query the database, but the connection state keeps in Closed state.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Comment: How are you querying the database? Linq-to-sql will open and close the connection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about connection pooling. this is a good reference to learn how to make the best of it:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/connection-pooling

copied from the link:

- Be sure your connections use the same connection string each time.
  Connection pooling only works if the connection string is the same.
  If the connection string is different, then a new connection will be
  opened.
- Only open a connection when you need it, not before.
- Close your connection as soon as you are done using it.
- Don't leave a connection open if it is not being used.
- Be sure to drop any temporary objects before closing a connection.
- Be sure to close any user-defined transactions before closing a connection.
- Don't use application roles if you want to take advantage of connection
  pooling.

Comment: Thanks, so that's why the connection is Opened and Closed.